# Form does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to have a button that will allow me to create a new instance of a form or if i have already created it just make it pop up again.

```
     public void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         if (!Form2Created)
         {
             Form2 Form_Prop = new Form2();
             Form_Prop.Show();
             Form2Created = true;
         }
         else
         {
             Form_Prop.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
         }
     }
```

The problem is that Form_Prop "does not exist in the context" (I know for sure it will because I'm canceling the attempts to close it and just minimizing it)

How can I work around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to make Form_Prop a member field in your class (where you have the `toolStripButton1_Click` even defined. You can then also get rid of the Form2Created field:

```
 Form2 Form_Prop;

 public void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (Form_Prop == null)
     {
         Form_Prop = new Form2();
         Form_Prop.Show();
     }
     else
     {
         Form_Prop.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to read [Scopes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Now the answer to your question. You are declaring the instance of your **form** within the **if statement** which means it is **not accessible** outside it. Therefore, you should declare it outside as

```
Form2 Form_Prop;
public void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         if (Form_Prop == null)
         {
             Form_Prop = new Form2();
             Form_Prop.Show();       

         }
     else
     {
         Form_Prop.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Form2 Form_Prop;
public void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form_Prop = Form_Prop ?? new Form2();
    Form_Prop.Show();
    Form_Prop.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
}
```